# List link of paginator

Tags: xslt

I need to generate a list of links, as the maximum value, I want to do is a paginator.

Example: this variable extracts the maximum number of links.

```
  <xsl:variable name="countPages" 
         select="substring-after(substring-before(
                     //x:div[@class='navBarBottomText']/x:span, ')'), 'till ' )" />
```

This case is: **30**, this value is the total of links.

**file XSLT:**

```
  <xsl:template match="//x:div[@class='navBarBottomText']" >
    <xsl:call-template name="paginator"/>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template name="paginator">
    <xsl:param name="pos" select="number(0)"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="not($pos >= countPages)">
        <link href="{concat('localhost/link=' + $pos)}" />
        <xsl:call-template name="paginator">
          <xsl:with-param name="pos" select="$pos + 1" />
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise/>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
```

The result should be something like:

```
<link href="localhost/link=0" />
<link href="localhost/link=1" />
<link href="localhost/link=2" />
<link href="localhost/link=3" />
<link href="localhost/link=4" />
<link href="localhost/link=5" />
<link href="localhost/link=6" />
.....
```

missing some parameter?. Thanks.

Comment: What does your current result look like? Where is the `paginator` template being called?

Comment: Sorry, i edit post, the result is 'page white', Error: The template 'paginator' not defined in this stylesheet.

Comment: AntonMM, Could you, please, edit the question and provide the source XML document on which the transformation should be performed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You could do this the way you wanted -- just use a proper variable reference:**

**Replace**:

```
<xsl:when test="not($pos >= countPages)">
```

**with**:

```
<xsl:when test="not($pos >= $countPages)">
```

**Here I assume that the variable `$countPages` is globally defined (visible).**

---

**A non-recursive solution**:

```
<xsl:variable name="vDoc" select="document('')"/>

<xsl:for-each select=
  "($vDoc//node() | $vDoc//@* | $vDoc//namespace::*)[not(position() >= $countPages)]">

  <link href="localhost/link={position() -1}" />
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Ups¡¡... error sintaxis. sorry. other problem resolved is in: concat('1' + $pos). thanks.

Comment: @AntonMM, NP. Please, see also the non-recursive solution (added a few minutes ago), which is more efficient and robust.